# Parse text from an HTML page

Tags: php, html-parsing

I know it is possible to get information (text) from another page.

For example, on the page at http://www.page.com/ is a `div` named `news`.
How can I get the text from this div?

Comment: You need to clarify your intentions, do you with to be at www.one.com and collect data from www.two.com ?

Comment: Unless you own the other page, it isn't really nice to grab and parse the content of someone else's page and can create a lot of overhead and use up a lot of bandwidth even if you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's what [HTML Simple DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is for amongst other options.

**Example:**

```
$html  = file_get_html('http://www.page.com/');
$mydiv = $html->find('div[id=news]', 0)->plaintext;
```

Comment: +1 for using HTML simple dom parser which is similar to jQuery in terms of selectors :) 
however please don't forget to use `clear()` method when using multiple instances of HTML DOM (i.e. in iteration) as it's easy to reach the memory limit using this library :)

Comment: @migajek: thanks and sure this is just an example, OP is supposed to visit their site for more info about it.

Comment: I'm afraid that they do not state anywhere that is recommended to use "clear", that's why I've written it here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use an [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).